# Symfony 2 : Access database inside FormBuilder

Tags: database, symfony, formbuilder

I'm building a form which contains a *category* field. I need a choice list to do that, but I don't find out how to fill this choice list with the several categories stored in the database.

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {
  $builder->add('item', 'text', array('label' => 'Item'));
  $builder->add('category', 'choice', array(
    'choices'   => ???,
    'label' => 'Category'
  ));
}
```

How can I get the categories from the database?
(I can't seem to access `$this->getDoctrine()` inside this class.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use type `entity` instead of `choice`

```
$builder
  ->add('entity_property', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'Namespace\\To\\Entity',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $repository) {
       return $repository->createQueryBuilder('q')
          ->where('q.a_field = yourvalue');
     }
));
```

**Edit:**

Two ways for using custom parameters in your query. In both situations, the parameters are injected from outside, so your FormType don't need any references to the session or request objects or whatever.

1- Pass required parameters to your constructor

```
class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    private $custom_value;

    public function __construct($custom_value) {
        $this->custom_value = $custom_value;
    }

    // ...
}
```

in your `buildForm()` you must copy the value to local variable and make it available for the query_builder callback:

```
public function buildForm(/*...*/) {
   $my_custom_value = $this->custom_value;

   // ...
       'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $repository) use ($my_custom_value) {
           return $repository->createQueryBuilder('q') 
               ->where('q.a_field = :my_custom_value')
               ->setParameter('my_custom_value', $my_custom_value);
       }

   // ...
}
```

2- use the `$options` parameter of the `buildForm` method.

First you have to define a default value by overriding `getDefaultOptions`:

```
public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return array(
        'my_custom_value' => 'defaultvalue'
    );
}
```

Then you can pass it from your controller in the third argument of the `createForm` method.

```
$this->createForm(new YourFormType(), $entity, array('my_custom_value' => 'custom_value'));
```

Now the value should be available through the `$options` parameter of youru buildForm method. Pass it to the callback as described above.

Comment: Thanks I just found the answer too by reading the related posts ^^ One more question though, the select list generated seems to take the primary key of the entity as a default value, is it possible to use another property for that ?

Comment: I don't think that there is an option to use another property as value field. The documentations has no hint about this (http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/entity.html). A solution might be, to pass a custom array in your Type-constructor, and use the choice type again. Than you can build your array from your controller with a custom structure.

Comment: Okay thanks, a last question : how can I use a dynamic parameter inside my query (like some session var) ?

Comment: I edited my answer. There are to examples of what you can do.

Answer (score 2):

### In Symfony 2.1

You now have to use the **OptionsResolverInterface** within the **setDefaultOptions** method. Here is the code you would have to use if you wanted to retrieve the options (using the same example as the accepted answer)

---

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){

    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

   $my_custom_value = $options[custom_value];

   // ...
       'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $repository) use ($my_custom_value) {
           return $repository->createQueryBuilder('q') 
               ->where('q.a_field = :my_custom_value')
               ->setParameter('my_custom_value', $my_custom_value);
       }

   // ...

}
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'my_custom_value' => 'defaultvalue'
        ));
    }
```

You still pass the options in the same way:

```
$this->createForm(new YourFormType(), $entity, array('my_custom_value' => 'custom_value'));
```

Comment: The original way still seems to work, but thanks for posting this, it is a more Symfonic way to do this!

Comment: But what if I haven't created repository?